# Fatal error : Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in

Tags: php, mysql, insert

tengo problemas para ingresar datos en mi base, da este error Fatal error
: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\secciones\alumnos.php:34 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\secciones\alumnos.php(34): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\secciones\vista_alumnos.php(2): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in
C:\xampp\htdocs\app\secciones\alumnos.php
on line
34
la linea 34 es el  $consulta->execute();

```
include_once '../configuraciones/bd.php';
$conexionBD=BD::crearInstancia();

$Matricula = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '';
$Nombre=isset($_POST['Nombre']) ? $_POST['Nombre'] : '';
$PrimerApellido=isset($_POST['Primer_Apellido']) ? $_POST['Primer_Apellido'] : '';
$SegundoApellido=isset($_POST['Segundo_Apellido']) ? $_POST['Segundo_Apellido'] : '';
$curp=isset($_POST['curp']) ? $_POST['curp'] : '';
$Grupo=isset($_POST['Grupo']) ? $_POST['Grupo'] : '';
$Email=isset($_POST['Email_institucional']) ? $_POST['Email_institucional'] : '';
$Carrera=isset($_POST['Carrera']) ? $_POST['Carrera'] : '';
$Grupor=isset($_POST['Grupo_Referente']) ? $_POST['Grupo_Referente'] : '';
$Contrasena=isset($_POST['Contrasena']) ? $_POST['Contrasena']: '';

$cursos = isset($_POST['cursos']) ? $_POST['cursos'] : '';
$accion=isset($_POST['accion']) ? $_POST['accion'] : '';

if ($accion != '') {
    switch ($accion) {
        case 'agregar':
            $sql = "INSERT INTO alumnosinf (Matricula, Nombre, Primer Apellido, Segundo Apellido, curp, Grupo, Email institucional, Carrera, Grupo Referente, Contrasena) VALUES (:id, :Nombre, :Primer_Apellido, :Segundo_Apellido, :curp, :Grupo, :Email_institucional, :Carrera, :Grupo_Referente, :Contrasena)";
            $consulta = $conexionBD->prepare($sql);
            $consulta->bindParam(':id',  $Matricula);
            $consulta->bindParam(':Nombre', $Nombre);
            $consulta->bindParam(':Primer Apellido', $PrimerApellido);
            $consulta->bindParam(':Segundo Apellido', $SegundoApellido);
            $consulta->bindParam(':curp', $curp);
            $consulta->bindParam(':Grupo', $Grupo);
            $consulta->bindParam(':Email institucional', $Email);
            $consulta->bindParam(':Carrera', $Carrera);
            $consulta->bindParam(':Grupo Referente', $Grupor);
            $consulta->bindParam(':Contrasena', $Contrasena);
            $consulta->execute();
        break;
```

Comment: En los `bindParam` tienes varios marcadores mal escritos, omitiste el `_` en `:Primer_Apellido`, `:Segundo_Apellido`, `:Email institucional` y en `:Grupo Referente`. Por otra parte, deberías evitar nombres de columna con espacios en blanco, son problemáticos.

Comment: muchas gracias, me funciono, tienes razón con los espacios en blanco